# In the attention mechanism, why don't we normalize after multiplying values?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, transformer, attention-mechanism

As this [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21237/23811) says:

> In scaled dot product attention, we scale our outputs by dividing the
> dot product by the square root of the dimensionality of the matrix:
>
> [image]
>
> The reason why is stated that this constrains the distribution of the weights of the output to have a standard deviation of 1.

My question is why don't we do the same after multiplying to $V$(values) for the same reason?

Answer (score 0):

I mean you *could*. The standardization here is to control the variance of the dot product as otherwise, since the softmax exponentiates, the weightings of the softmax are likely to be very sparse (i.e. a weight of near $1$ applied to the largest dot product value). This is not very helpful as the gradients will be extremely small for values with softmax weights of $0$.

As for normalizing the products, you can do so, and I believe the architecture does include Normalization layers for this purpose.